# Ошибка при присвоении значения ссылке структуры

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, память

Что я делаю не так, почему ошибка при дебаггинге в Qt?

```
struct __regHookKeys {
    short alt;
    short key;
    short flag;
    short  altState;
    short altTime;
    int countAlt;
} _regHookKeys, *regHookKeys;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, NULL);
    regHookKeys->alt=1;//тут ошибка
    return a.exec();
}
```

Ошибка:

> Signal received
>   Signal name: SIGSEGV
>   Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

Comment: Память под структуру-то выделили? Куда указывает `regHookKeys`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На что у вас указывает `regHookKeys` при обращении к этому указателю? Судя по всему, он объявлен в глобальной области видимости, инициализирован нулевым значением, и не изменяется в `main`.

Значит, тут

```
regHookKeys->alt=1;
```

вы разыменовываете несуществующую область памяти. Вот и ошибка...

**Update**

Тут меня без меня женили - добавили вот этот текст:

> Дополню немного ответ, чтоб не было ошибки надо так:

```
regHookKeys = new __regHookKeys;
regHookKeys->alt=1;
```

но я должен упомянуть, что это не единственный способ избежать подобной ошибки. Возможны варианты, когда указатель используется для указания на структуру, определенную в другом месте, или, например, возвращается из некоторой функции. Словом, возможны варианты; просто "заткнуть рот" программе, чтоб не возмущалась, без понимания, что именно происходит - способ не лучший.

Comment: Да действительно, туплю